# Count no. of characters in a string without using any generic function provided by QTP, like split/len/Instr etc

Tags: qtp

Is there anyway possible to count the numbers of characters in a string without using any String manipulation function provided by QTP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your motivation for this question.

QTP tests are VBScript based, do you mean using plain VBScript? If so you use [`Len(str)`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_len.asp).

If you want to avoid VBScript functions I must say I don't know and I don't care. The launguage has built in functions for a reason and that reason isn't to avoid using them.

Comment: This Question had been asked to many people in an Interview and it was left un-answered by almost everyone that day. I came close but could not figure it as i was quite new to QTP that time. As of now I do know the answer, but wanted to explore if there are any other ideas with us.